# Problem in Making the X in a div To be used to make the div disappear

Tags: javascript, html, css

pls I need help
I have been trying to develop a div which contain a message and a x. When the x is clicked, the div supposed to disappear. But that isn't happening.

This is the source code:

```js
document.querySelector(".closeMsg").addEventListener("click", function () {
  var removeReplyBx = document.getElementById("contactReplyBx");
  removeReplyBx.style.display = "none";
});
```

```css
#contactReplyBx{
  display: block;
  z-index: 999999999;
  background: #009e66;
  padding: auto;
  min-height: 4vh;
  line-height: 4vh;
}

.replyMsg{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  letter-spacing: 0.2em;
  padding-left: 20vw;
  padding-right: 25vw;
  padding-top: auto;
  padding-bottom: auto;
}
.closeMsg{
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #009e66;
  padding-left: 0.3em;
  padding-right: 0.3em;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: 500;
}
```

```html
<div id="contactReplyBx">
  <span class="replyMsg">Thank you! Your message has been sent.</span>
  <button class="closeMsg">x</button>
</div>
```

I have searched for answer on the internet but haven't seen any that solves the problem

[The div is green located at the upper part of the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HnLoE.jpg)

Comment: the code you have is working if your idea of making it disappear is to set the display to none

Comment: It's working for me

Comment: yes it should work

Comment: Please can you show me the code you used @daisy

Comment: @Ramesh Reddy, yes that's what I want to but it doesn't disappear

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I just discovered that I had placed the script tag at the bottom instead of the top.